# As CocoaPods 1.1.0+ is required to build Alamofire 4.0.0+,platform :ios, '10.0'. how to use alamofire 4.0.0+ under iOS 10?

Tags: alamofire

As CocoaPods 1.1.0+ is required to build Alamofire 4.0.0+,platform :ios, '10.0'.
how to use alamofire 4.0.0+ under iOS 10?

Answer (score 0):

CocoaPods 1.1.0+ is indeed required but as stated in the [Readme](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/README.md) the minimum iOS version is 9.0. The Podfile given there is just an example so you should write `platform :ios, '9.0'` to target below iOS 10.